# How to print parts of an array on the the same line in a function, without having space?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to print the string character by character but there is always white space in between. Can't seem to figure out how to get rid of it. Is there a way to still print the string animated without having the spaces?

```py
    import time

    starting_text = 'Welcome to CHOOSE YOUR OWN ADVENTURE!' 
    new_starting_text = list(starting_text)

    for x in new_starting_text:
        print(x),
        time.sleep(.1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of converting the String to a list, you can simply call the replace function to replace the space to empty String.

```
starting_text = = 'Welcome to CHOOSE YOUR OWN ADVENTURE!' 
new_starting_text = starting_text.replace(" ", "")
#result = 'WelcometoCHOOSEYOUROWNADVENTURE!'

#to print it character by character you can loop through the new string
for x in new_starting_text:
    print(x)
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**For Python 3**

```py
import time

starting_text = 'Welcome to CHOOSE YOUR OWN ADVENTURE!' 
new_starting_text = list(starting_text)

for x in new_starting_text:
    print(x, end='')
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Output

> Welcome to CHOOSE YOUR OWN ADVENTURE!

**For Python 2**

```py
from __future__ import print_function
import time

starting_text = 'Welcome to CHOOSE YOUR OWN ADVENTURE!' 
new_starting_text = list(starting_text)

for x in new_starting_text:
    print(x, end='')
    time.sleep(.1)
```

Output

> Welcome to CHOOSE YOUR OWN ADVENTURE!

From `help(print)`:

```py
print(...)
    print(value, ..., sep='', end='\n', file=sys.stdout)

    Prints the values to a stream, or to sys.stdout by default.
    Optional keyword arguments:
    file: a file-like object (stream); defaults to the current sys.stdout.
    sep:  string inserted between values, default a space.
    end:  string appended after the last value, default a newline.
```

Comment: @Chris Added for Python 2 also. Please check it

Answer (score 0):

Try using this modified code:

```
import time
import sys

starting_text = 'Welcome to CHOOSE YOUR OWN ADVENTURE!'
new_starting_text = list(starting_text)

for x in new_starting_text:
    print(x,end = ''),
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(.1)
```

std.stdout.flush() will bring the cursor back to the first line eliminating the new line and keeping the animation you want. Hope this helps you!